# Django routes - check route from DB

Tags: django, routes, url-routing

Morning,

With my django website, I want to make the urls as short as possible.
So instead of, 
/user/john
/user/ronald

I just want it like /john and /ronald

So in my routes I have it configured that all the requests go to one

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     ....
    (r'^about/$', 'frontend.views.about'),
    (r'^(.*?)/$', 'users.views.index')
)
```

which means basically that all requests will be handled by the users controller if not handled else where, which isn't to bad.

But I want to do the same cakes.

so instead of /cakes/chocolate-coated-cake just have /chocolate-coated-cake

So really, it'd be nice if in my users method, instead of raising a 404 I could just some how call try next route, so it's conditional on a DB field.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I'll prefer to have a separate dispatcher view (not related to users because it is not about users). There you could set up order of models in a list and iterate through it until the first sucess and call the appropriate view (user view, cake view) with this result as an argument).

P.S. Hope that you will not have a user and a cake with the same name :)

Comment: Agreed. You must have a single dispatch view that would systematically try to lookup the slug in each model in order and then delegate to the appropriate view when a match was found. However, this is going to put extra strain on your DB, and you'll likely have problems with slugs not being unique. It's better to just leave the standard prefix. Having `/user/` or `/cake/` in front of the URL doesn't make it that much longer and is worth not having to do this.